# Debugging Chrome with windbg: Put a breakbpoint in chrome.dll

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, windbg, chromium

I'm trying to debug an official chrome release (44.0.2403.130 m) with WinDbg. I follow the steps in https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows but I'm not able to put a breakpoint in `chrome.dll!extensions::api::developer_private::LoadDirectory()` method.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the symbols for chrome.dll?

Comment: Yes. Actually I managed to do what I needed. I will post a solution shortly.

Comment: Will you post a solution?